# Must a $30$-regular graph contain a path of length at least $20$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let simple graph $G$ be a $30$-regular graph. Is it true that $G$ must contain a path of length at least $20$?

Comment: What do you mean by tools? Its simple regular graph no other information is given. If this is not true they wanted us to give example graph with path with length at most 19.

Comment: By tools I mean: remember way back in algebra 1, you learned to factor quadratics, and then you learned about completing the square, and then you learned about the quadratic formula?  Depending on how far you'd gotten in that class, your approach to the question "solve this quadratic equation" would vary significantly.    The same is true here: while we could *probably* build the answer from the basic principles of graphs, by the time this question gets asked in a class or textbook we know vastly more than that - and the position of the question in the text can give hints on what to use.

Comment: We learnt not so much about graph theory. We did five six lessons just about basics, definitions. For this question all I know is definitions of simple graph, path and regular graphs.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351945/diameter-of-k-regular-graph) seems to be related to yours.

Comment: What happens if you choose an edge at each vertex?  Will you run out of edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [survey paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.5167.pdf), theorem 5.5, if a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices has no path of length $k\ge2$ then the number of edges of $G$ is $$e(G) \le \frac{k-2}{2}n$$  With $k=20$ this gives $e(G)\le9n$ but since $G$ is $30-$regular, we know $e(G)=15n.$  Thus, there must be a path of length $20$.

The paper gives no proof, but says that the theorem was proved by Erdös and Gallai [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/321c/f0f9c160f9a3f8ee707e9ec940762cca27e8.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the full strength of Erdős-Gallai here. As @MichaelBurr indicates, we can be greedy. Being greedy means doing exactly what you think you should do.

Let's suppose we want to find this path in our graph: let's start a any old vertex. Now let's move to a new vertex along an edge in our graph. Let's move to another new vertex, and so on, making our path. Now how could we get stuck? That is, when can we no longer extend our path? Let's say we've made a path with $k$ vertices in it, and we want to extend it to a path of length $k+1$. If we are prevented from extending the path, it must be that all of the edges incident to an endpoint of our path *must be incident to vertices already in our path*, because a path cannot go through the same vertex twice. But again, when can this happen? Each vertex has $30$ edges incident to it, but our path only has length $k$. So if $30 \geq k$, we can extend our path! By this greedy argument, we can extend our path possibly until it has length $31$.

Comment: I just realized this, and came here to edit my answer, but found that you had anticipated me.

Comment: @saulspatz, no problem. This greedy argument is usually how one starts out to prove stronger statements like Erdős-Gallai. I figure it's best for a beginner graph theory student. Note too that this necessary path of length $31$ is tight: we could take a complete graph on $31$ vertices.